# KeyNotFoundException when adding view to region

Tags: wpf, prism, mef, region

Using `MEF` and `Prism`. I have a pane marked with a region name:

```
<telerik:RadPaneGroup prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MyModuleRegion" />
```

Due to the nature of the software, this pane is not always created. Basically, it *may* be created at some point but we don't know when. Hence, `MyModule` fails to attach its view to "MyModuleRegion" - a `KeyNotFoundException` exception is thrown since the region does not exist:

```
// Region still not created! Now what?!
IRegion region = regionManager.Regions["MyModuleRegion"]; // <-- !!
region.Add(view, "My Module");
```

**How do I map the view of `MyModule` to the "MyModuleRegion" region at runtime?** That is, when the region is created through xaml, the view is injected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use View Discovery? :)

```
    this.RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.MyModuleRegion, typeof(MyView));
```

It should work... I hope! :)

Comment: This is one way to do it, so I'll accept the answer. In my case, I was using `AutoPopulateExportedViewsBehavior` which was not correctly added to my bootstrapper's `AggregateCatalog`.

Comment: @l33t so maybe you could add your own answer? :)